# Update and Save text on a Form after the macro finishes

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have a macro to delete values from a table I would like to add the last time this macro run.
I manage to find a way to input Date inside of it and save, but when I open Access again, it has the original value in it.

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Comando0_Click()
dataate = InputBox("Periodo a ser deletado até [DD/MM/AAAA]:")

If IsDate(dataate) Then
    dataate = Format(CDate(dataate), "dd\/mm\/yyyy")
End If

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim count As Long

    Set qdf = CurrentDb().QueryDefs("Teste 1")
    With qdf
        .Parameters("[prmDataAte]").Value = CDate(dataate)
        .Execute dbFailOnError
        count = .RecordsAffected
    End With

    MsgBox " " & count & " registros foram apagados da tbl_tabela_de_preco"
    
Me.teste3.Caption = Now
DoCmd.Save acForm, Me.Name
    
End Sub
```

So far I tried using textbox and labels and had encountered the same problem.
And tried other codes that i found:

```
    theFormName = Me.OpenArgs
    Set theform = Forms.Item("Formulário1")

    
Me.teste3.Caption = Now
theform.teste2.Caption = "Dados excluídos até: " & dataate
DoCmd.Save acForm, Me.Name
DoCmd.Save , "Formulário1"
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo
```

Answer (score 1):

Issues with your code:

```
If IsDate(dataate) Then
    dataate = Format(CDate(dataate), "dd\/mm\/yyyy")
End If
```

This has no `Else` or `Exit Sub` clause, so the rest of the code will run always, even if no valid date was entered.

```
Me.teste3.Caption = Now
DoCmd.Save acForm, Me.Name
```

You can set control properties (like Caption) in Form View, but you cannot save them permanently. So the `DoCmd.Save` has no effect here.

You would have to do this in Design View. But this is not a good way to do this.

Better: in `Form_Load()`, read the date from the table where you saved it with the update query. Then set the caption with that date.